# in flink, I can`t map String to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, apache-flink, fastjson

source code:
source a String,and I try to map it into JSONObject,and i failed.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String\[\] args) throws Exception {
//TODO 1.
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setParallelism(1);

        //TODO 2.
        DataStreamSource<String> inputDS = env.fromElements("{\"bill_info\":{\"ADD_TIME\":\"2022-11-12 16:05:28:418\",\"ORDER_ID\":\"f3e60c5f-78f6-4ec6-bab6-98b177f7cb67\",\"ADDER_NO\":\"0706\",\"UPDATER_NO\":\"0706\",\"S_USER_ID\":\"s68\",\"B_USER_ID\":\"b77\",\"BILL_ID\":\"8687b584-038c-498c-8f97-ec1ca197da96\",\"ADDER_NAME\":\"sss\",\"UPDATE_TIME\":\"2022-11-12 16:05:28:418\",\"UPDATER_NAME\":\"ssss\"}}");
    
    
        //TODO 3.
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<JSONObject> jsonObjDS = inputDS.process(new ProcessFunction<String, JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(String value, ProcessFunction<String, JSONObject>.Context ctx, Collector<JSONObject> out) throws Exception {
                JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.parseObject(value);
                out.collect(jsonObject);
            }
        });
        jsonObjDS.print();
    
        env.execute();
    }

}
```

error:Assigned key must not be null!

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Assigned key must not be null!
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Assigned key must not be null!

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried map,flatmap,process.They all failed when my collector collecting them.
after debug,i found that String have been parsed into JSONObject,but just can not be collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to compile, I had to change the code slightly, to

```java
public void processElement(
    String value,
    ProcessFunction<String, JSONObject>.Context ctx,
    Collector<JSONObject> out) throws Exception {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(value);
        out.collect(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

and it works fine. It prints out

```
{"bill_info":{"ADDER_NAME":"sss","ADDER_NO":"0706","UPDATER_NAME":"ssss","UPDATER_NO":"0706","BILL_ID":"8687b584-038c-498c-8f97-ec1ca197da96","ADD_TIME":"2022-11-12 16:05:28:418","ORDER_ID":"f3e60c5f-78f6-4ec6-bab6-98b177f7cb67","S_USER_ID":"s68","B_USER_ID":"b77","UPDATE_TIME":"2022-11-12 16:05:28:418"}}
```

I used

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Note, however, that's generally not a good idea to be sending around JSONObjects -- they are expensive to serialize and deserialize. It would be better to deserialize the JSON to a POJO, along the lines of what is shown in  [this recipe](https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/deserializing-json-from-kafka-to-apache-flink-pojo/).